# Updating MySQL Database every 5 minutes with data from an API

Tags: python, mysql, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot that gathers a users stats from a game using an API.

I currently have a function that is meant to be a background task aka on a different thread. unfortunately it makes my bot lag out whilst its running and as its meant to be doing it every 5mins, this is less than ideal.

I am basically looking for a solution that will allow me to use the bot and update the stats every 5mins.

I am hoping to use some other solution with I haven't got any idea of to allow this to not make my bot hang.

They most annoying thing is that the stats are coming from an API so it need to do a for loop to execute.

here is the function:

````py
async def update_playlists(self, platform, username):
        print("-----\nUPDATING RL RANKS DB - DO NOT SHUTDOWN")
        async with self.bot.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                sql = "SELECT `username`, `platform` FROM `player_ranks`"
                await cur.execute(sql)
                players = await cur.fetchall()
                for player in players:
                    ranks = []
                    username, platform = player
                    print(f"-----\n{username} ranks are being updated")
                    playlists = self.get_playlists(platform, username)
                    for gameMode in GameModes:
                        if gameMode == GameModes.CASUAL.value:
                            continue
                        try:
                            playlist = next((p for p in playlists['data'] if p['attributes']['playlistId'] == gameMode))
                            ranks += (playlist['stats']['tier']['metadata']['name'],
                                      playlist['stats']['division']['metadata']['name'],
                                      playlist['stats']['rating']['value'])

                        except StopIteration:
                            ranks += ("n/a", "n/a", "0")
                            pass
                    sql = "UPDATE player_ranks SET `Duel_Rank`=%s, `Duel_Div`=%s, `Duel_MMR`=%s, `Doubles_Rank`=%s, `Doubles_Div`=%s, `Doubles_MMR`=%s, `Solo_Standard_Rank`=%s, `Solo_Standard_Div`=%s, `Solo_Standard_MMR`=%s, `Standard_Rank`=%s, `Standard_Div`=%s, `Standard_MMR`=%s, `Hoops_Rank`=%s, `Hoops_Div`=%s, `Hoops_MMR`=%s, `Rumble_Rank`=%s, `Rumble_Div`=%s, `Rumble_MMR`=%s, `Dropshot_Rank`=%s, `Dropshot_Div`=%s, `Dropshot_MMR`=%s, `Snowday_Rank`=%s, `Snowday_Div`=%s, `Snowday_MMR`=%s WHERE `username`=%s"
                    await cur.execute(sql, (*ranks, username))
                    await conn.commit()
                    playerdata = self.get_playerinfo(platform, username)
                    wins_: int = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['wins']['value']
                    assists_: int = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['assists']['value']
                    goals_: int = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['goals']['value']
                    goalShotRatio_: float = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['goalShotRatio']['value']
                    mvps = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['mVPs']['value']
                    saves = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['saves']['value']
                    shots = playerdata['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['shots']['value']
                    sql = "UPDATE player_stats SET `wins`=%s, `assists`=%s, `goals`=%s, `goalshot`=%s,`mvp`=%s, `saves`=%s, `shots`=%s WHERE `username`=%s"
                    await cur.execute(sql, (wins_, assists_, goals_, goalShotRatio_, mvps, saves, shots, username))
                    await conn.commit()```
````

Comment: Do you want me to help you write a DatabaseManager?

Comment: If it wouldn't be too much trouble! That would be amazing

Comment: Contact my email with the requirements and I'll see what I can do. kissosrazz@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the bot doing the updating of the database you can have it write all the stats to a file (json or plain text) and then use a seperate program that accesses said file every 5 minutes and reads the data, parses it into the database and saves everything. If you use this "DatabaseManager" you can save some valuable time and efficiency for your poor bot ;)

```
Note: to further increase the efficiency of the DatabaseManager
you can write it in a lower level language than python such as C++ or C#
```

Comment: any program you can recommend?

Comment: write it yourself, it shouldn't be very complicated.
I can offer my help...

Answer (score 0):

If you have massive updates then in any case the operation will take substantial time, currently you "await" all the update operations, so you kinda do all this synchronously.

One solution would be not to wait and just log results (not sure how it can be done in python).

Another specific to MySQL solution can be MySQL events - with [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) you can schedule a stored procedure execution and it will run in the background and your bot virtually won't have any lag.

Comment: I am unsure how I would even make that an SQL event but thanks for your answer.

Comment: If all your updates can be moved to a stored procedure then CREATE EVENT can invoke this procedure and it will run separately, you don't need waiting for results. I thought this is  the requirement.